# How is LanguageNegotiationUrlFallback used?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I've been trying to get language negotiation to work on my site, in particular to try to find a workaround for [this bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/2189267), which basically means I *must* have LanguageNegotiationUrl enabled and above all other detection methods in order for content to be editable.

I discovered this class - [LanguageNegotiationUrlFallback](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21language%21src%21Plugin%21LanguageNegotiation%21LanguageNegotiationUrlFallback.php/class/LanguageNegotiationUrlFallback/8.3.x).

Why doesn't 'URL fallback' appear in the list of detection methods at /admin/config/regional/language/detection? Does anybody know what triggers it?